# Integrating Facebook Connect Login/Registration with Zend Framework Application

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting, facebook

I have a social networking website built upon the zend framework. My application also has extensively used htaccess's urlrewriting feature. The thing is that I want to incorporate facebook connect so users can login using their facebook logins as well. I'm stuck just on the part of how do I set it up.

Like I know you have to created an xd_reciever.htm file and it shoudl be in the smae folder where the facebook connect call code would be however in an MVC environment + rewritten urls how do I set it up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xd_receiver.htm file was required for the old Facebook Connect. This has been superceded by the new FB API which no longer requires the xd_receiver file. See more here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web#login